# Vue problem with display of json response from rest api

Tags: javascript, json, spring, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a problem with displaying my response which i get from rest API. After I get response I'm using JSON.stringify to make it like below, then I'm calling action which call a mutation which save it in my store in `cars: []`. The variable `cars[]` in my store and response looks like below so everything is going fine with this.

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "vin":11111,
    "register_number":"asdasd",
    "cost":1.32,
    "latitude":50.875883,
    "longitude":20.634377,
    "service":false,
    "reservation":false
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "vin":2222,
    "register_number":"asdasd",
    "cost":1.3,
    "latitude":50.4244,
    "longitude":20.3323,
    "service":true,
    "reservation":false
  }
]
```

Then i'm trying to display it. I use vue getter to get this response from store, if I use getter like
`<li> {{gettername}} </li>` then I can see my data like above but when i want to display them using `<v-for="car in CARS" v-bind:key="car"> {{car}} </v-for>` then due this key i think i'm getting strange things like this:

```
[
{
"
i
d
"
:
1
,
"
v
i
n
"
: (when every single sign is in another row ..)
```

Like every singe letter is taken as a object or something.... i just wanna display in rows parameters of my car like:

"id":1,"vin":11111,"register_number":"asdasd","cost":1.32,"latitude":50.875883,"longitude":20.634377,"service":false,"reservation":false
"id":2,"vin":2222,"register_number":"asdasd","cost":1.3,"latitude":50.4244,"longitude":20.3323,"service":true,"reservation":false

Then i need to bind them for editing and sending update request to my backend. 
Help me please to resolve and understand this problem.
Best regards!

Comment: What's your `CARS` property look like?

Comment: Why are you using **JSON.stringify()**? That transforms a JSON object to a string, and when you loop over a string, you get every character - just like you described. Are you sure you need that **stringify**?

Comment: My CARS inside computed
computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['CAR_LIST']),
        CARS() {
            
            return this.$store.getters.CAR_LIST;
            
        }
    }

Comment: Thank You muka! stringify was the problem..when I removed it problem was solved! :D I love this community for fast and great answers!

Comment: I made this stringify because my object from response had a getters and setters so I though if I don't stringify it then my array would be with getters/setters too

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet to show the difference between a string and an array:

```js
(async function() {
  const todo = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      return json
    })

  const stringified = JSON.stringify(todo)

  console.log('JSON object:')
  console.log(todo)
  console.log('Stringified JSON:')
  console.log(stringified)
})();
```

In the snippet above we receive a **todo** JSON object, and then `console.log()` the object itself and a stringified version.